# How to publish and run asp.net core 1 & angular 2 application with IIS?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-1.0

How to deploy an angular 2 (2.0.0-rc.4) and ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Core 1 – sdk version 1.0.0-preview2-003121) on IIS?

Comment: With regards to publishing to IIS - here is the doc that explains it https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html and here is my post explaining how things work under the hood and how to troubleshoot:
https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to docs:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html

I have created a 5 min video on how to setup angular 2 and aspnetcore

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O3VgA1jthJE

If you are in Visual Studio, use `Publish` button to deploy.

The deployed version will be exported into  `wwwroot` folder